# Ionic 4 - build apk size become half of original size after ionic repair

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am surprised about ionic 4. I created an app in ionic 4 and build its apk. At that time its size is 20MB. But one day I build after run this command **ionic repair**. At that time my apk size become 10MB and working all functions perfectly. But after 5 or 10 builds it returned to 20MB again. I don't know what is happening. If any one know about this please share with me.

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest Angular 8 then you should get a big drop in the total size. I dont know about your experience though - did you try ionic repair again to see if the magic happened twice? :) If so then my next stop would be to look at the source code and see what ionic repair is doing!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the differential loading introduced in angular 8, probably your repair updated your deps :)

https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27